# [BRAVOBET.DetailSoccerTableViewController likeBtn:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcbde464800'

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, parse.com, uibutton

Всем привет!Сделал кнопку Like в секции header. При нажатии не срабатывает кнопка и не суммируются клики.Подскажите как внедрить в header кнопку, или может я что то не то указал внутри функции кнопки.Нашел пример в appcoda урок instagramm-like  сервер Parse. Очень буду благодарен за помощь. Выдает такую ошибку.Вроде все задал правильно, уже пробовал изменять внутри кнопки функцию.Уже в storyboard лишнии функции и с ошибками удалил.Может кто нибудь помочь?
Вот мой код:

```
import UIKit

class CustomSoccerHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

    var clickBravisso: Soccer?

    @IBOutlet weak var bravoBtn: UIButton!{
        didSet {
            bravoBtn.layer.cornerRadius = bravoBtn.frame.size.width/2
            bravoBtn.layer.masksToBounds = true

        }
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var countBravo: UILabel!

    @IBAction func likeBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if (clickBravisso != nil) {

            if var clickBravissimo: Int = clickBravisso!.object(forKey: "bravissimo") as? Int {

                clickBravissimo += 1

                clickBravisso!.setObject(clickBravissimo, forKey: "bravissimo")
                clickBravisso!.saveInBackground()
                countBravo.text = "\(clickBravissimo)"

            }

        }
    }






    @IBOutlet weak var nameHeader: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var imageHeader: UIImageView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code



    }


    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "CustomSoccerHeaderView") as! CustomSoccerHeaderView

        header.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 280)
        header.bravoBtn.tag = section
        header.nameHeader.text = detailSoccer.detailTitleS
        header.countBravo.text = "\(detailSoccer.bravissimo)"
        header.bravoBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CustomSoccerHeaderView.likeBtn(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        detailSoccer.imagePrS.getDataInBackground { (data, error) in
            header.imageHeader.image = error == nil ? UIImage(data: data!) : nil
        }



        return header
    }
```

Comment: Совсем не понятно, чего вы ожидаете и что получаете вместо ожидаемого. Объясните более чётко.

Comment: Когда нажимаю на кнопку у меня добавляется новое событие с числом  клика 1.А не идет счетчик количество кликов.